# how could i prevent to upload exe file in java using content type?

Tags: java

I have to allow to upload all type of file except for executable files. How can I add a restriction for it?

```
public class FileUtility {
    private static final long MAX_SIZE_FILES = 1024 * 1024*10;

    public static  boolean isValidFileType(String mimeType){ 
        //i have to put restriction here 
        return false;
    }
    public  static boolean  isValidFileSize(long fileSize ) {
        if (MAX_SIZE_FILES< fileSize){
            return false;
        }         
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is an "_executable file_"? Windows `.exe`? `.com`? UNIX executable? You could check [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#Magic_numbers_in_files), but that will only get you so far - I would simply suggest that you don't execute them...

Comment: every type of executable file

Comment: yes it is only for exe file.i need to apply restriction for all like sh,apk,and other

Comment: How do you _get_ the mime type? It almost certain that it's entirely pointless to do what you want...

Comment: i get it from file content type

Comment: That's just a header then, sent by the client. The primary rule of secure web programming - never trust anything sent by the client. For example, I send you my executable virus with a content type of `application/json` or even `text/plain`. Ah, you say, but either of those should be interpret-able as text and a virus would be binary - fine, I choose `application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.binary.macroEnabled.12`. What now?

Comment: so what should i do?

Comment: That is a very complicated question, and the answer to it does not exist in general. Are you planning to run the uploaded binaries - then you need to virus scan them to hell, spin up a virtual machine or chroot jail, and run them in that - with absolutely to access to anything on the host machine. Are you planning on just storing them? Programs don't execute themselves, there is no reason to prevent the upload of binaries if they're just going to sit there...

Comment: ...Note that there is as likely to be an exploit (buffer overflow, etc) in some image processing library that causes an uploaded Jpeg to execute arbitrary code as there is to be some other exploit that causes those uploaded binaries to execute. In short, the internet is a very dangerous place - taking input from untrusted sources should never to done lightly.